# Partner referral sales have tanked two months after HTTPS migration, switch back?

Tags: seo, https, vps, migration

On march 2nd I migrated my website from http to https and also put the site on a new VPS that I configured.

I have 301'd all urls to https and I have no mixed content warnings.

I have also added the https url to Google Search Console and have seen traffic drop on the http url while it rises on the https url.

Through verification via statcounter and google analytics my traffic has stayed largely the same with perhaps some minimal drops. These could be seasonal as well because April and May tend to be slower months in this industry.

The revenue from my site is generated by sending visitors to a large corporate shopping presence where I get credit for the sale if and when one is made.

Today I contacted them directly because I had only had one sale in the last two months which is a dramatic drop. I wanted to find out if sales are just very slow right now or if something perhaps seemed off via their statistics. Their google analytics show my referrals to their site have pretty much been reduced to nothing since early March, right when I switched to HTTPS and the new server.

From my end:

- Traffic looks normal/as it should be via two tracking tools
- I am showing as many exit links to the partner in April and May as I had in January and February before the migration.
- HTTPS version on google search console shows good indexing and good/normal impressions and clicks etc.
- All testing/crawling verification of http to https migration works well with no noticeable or glaring issues.

Yet my sales have tanked and the company I send the traffic to says it has dropped to almost nothing.

I don't even know where to start. I am trying to find out if it could be something tracking wise on their end. At this point reverting to HTTP after two months seems like a horrible idea, but is this something I should consider or are there other migration points I need to look at?

Comment: Are you sending traffic to your partner's HTTPS site or to their HTTP site?

Comment: ahh good question, just checked and I am indeed linking to the http site of theirs.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have now updated the links so the traffic is being sent to the partners https site.

Comment: If it appears that you have similar traffic on your site to when it was http, with the same amount of traffic coming from organic search, and your audience is from the same general countries that it used to be from, and your on site analytics such as pages per session and time on site is the same, I would assume that your https conversion hasn't hurt sales. If anything, something is probably wrong with your affiliate partner. But if something seems to have changed regarding your traffic since the https conversion, you might want to switch back.